# Adding Strings in a JTextField

Tags: java, string, int, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm currently trying to play with the idea of making a code for a very basic calculator. I am able to make each of the buttons and make ActionListeners in order to have the button symbol show up on the JTextField, but now I'm trying to make the two Strings add. I know you can't add strings, but I'm not sure how exactly to change these strings into ints and add them. I thought of having the digits go into variables, but I believe that would be very inefficient.... Please take a look of my code.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class CalculatorWithLayouts {

 //Declaration of all calculator's components.
    JPanel windowContent;
    static JTextField displayField;
    JButton button0;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JButton button4;
    JButton button5;
    JButton button6;
    JButton button7;
    JButton button8;
    JButton button9;
    JButton buttonPoint;
    JButton buttonEqual;
    JButton buttonAdd;
    JButton buttonSub;
    JButton buttonTimes;
    JButton buttonDivide;
    JPanel p1;

    //Constructor creates the components in memory
    // and adds to the frame using combination of
    // BorderLayout and GridLayout
    CalculatorWithLayouts() {

        windowContent = new JPanel();

        //Set the layout manager for this panel;
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(bl);

        //Create the display field and place it in the 
        //North area of the window
        displayField = new JTextField(20);
        windowContent.add("North", displayField);

        //Create buttons using constructor of the
        //class JButton
        button0 = new JButton("0");
        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button2 = new JButton("2");
        button3 = new JButton("3");
        button4 = new JButton("4");
        button5 = new JButton("5");
        button6 = new JButton("6");
        button7 = new JButton("7");
        button8 = new JButton("8");
        button9 = new JButton("9");
        buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
        buttonEqual = new JButton("=");
        buttonAdd = new JButton("+");
        buttonSub = new JButton("-");
        buttonTimes = new JButton("x");
        buttonDivide = new JButton("÷");

        //Create the panel with the GridLayout
        //that will contain 12 buttons -
        // 10 numeric ones, and buttons with point
        // and equal sign
        p1 = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(4, 4);
        p1.setLayout(gl);

        //Add window controls to the panel p1
        p1.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new Press1());
        p1.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(new Press2());
        p1.add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener(new Press3());
        p1.add(buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new PressPlus());
        p1.add(button4);
        button4.addActionListener(new Press4());
        p1.add(button5);
        button5.addActionListener(new Press5());
        p1.add(button6);
        button6.addActionListener(new Press6());
        p1.add(buttonSub);
        buttonSub.addActionListener(new PressMinus());
        p1.add(button7);
        button7.addActionListener(new Press7());
        p1.add(button8);
        button8.addActionListener(new Press8());
        p1.add(button9);
        button9.addActionListener(new Press9());
        p1.add(buttonTimes);
        buttonTimes.addActionListener(new PressTimes());
        p1.add(buttonPoint);
        buttonPoint.addActionListener(new PressPoint());
        p1.add(button0); 
        button0.addActionListener(new Press0());
        p1.add(buttonEqual);
        buttonEqual.addActionListener(new PressEqual());
        p1.add(buttonDivide);
        buttonDivide.addActionListener(new PressDivide());

        //Add the panel p1 to the center area
        //of the window
        windowContent.add("Center", p1);
        //Create the frame and set its content panel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        //set the size of the window to be big enough
        //to accommodate all controls
        frame.pack();
        //Finally, display the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Press1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("1"));
        }   
    }
    static class Press2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("2"));
        }   
    }
    static class Press3 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("3"));
        }
    }
    static class Press4 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("4"));
        }           
    }       
    static class Press5 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("5"));
        }           
    }       
    static class Press6 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("6"));
        }           
    }       
    static class Press7 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("7"));
        }       
    }   
    static class Press8 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("8"));
        }           
    }       
    static class Press9 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("9"));
        }           
    }       
    static class Press0 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + String.valueOf("0"));
        }           
    }       
    static class PressPlus implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + " + ");
        }       
    }   
    static class PressMinus implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + " - ");
        }
    }
    static class PressTimes implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + " x ");
        }
    }
    static class PressDivide implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + " ÷ ");
        }
    }
    static class PressPoint implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + ".");
        }
    }
    static class PressEqual implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText(displayField.getText() + " =");
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(displayField.getText()));
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: why not use this?
    `Integer.parseInt("1234");`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `String` to a `float` with `Float.parseFloat(str)`. But the more complicated part is to split the String into numbers and process them in the right order. You didn't think about brackets yet, did you?

My approach would be to convert the String into a tree.

```
(1 + 5 * 4 - 2)(51 - 4 / 20)
```

should be converted to this: (I know this isn't easy!)

```
                 *
       *                   /
  +         -          -      20
1   5     3   2     51   4
```

Answer (score 0):

**New Solution Based on What You Have told e in Comments:**
Lets just say the input is 1 + 2....

```
 String s = jTextField1.getText(); //gets Text
 String[] s2 = s.split(" "); //Now you have 1,+,2 in different indexes
```

Now we need a method to check if the index is an operation.

```
 public boolean isOperation(String s)
 {
   if(s.equals("+")||s.equals("-")||s.equals("/")||s.equals("*"))
   {
         return true;
   }
   else
   return false;
 }
```

Now that we have a method to check that....

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<String> Operation = new ArrayList<String>();

 //the number of operations must be the number of integers-1
 if((listsize()-Operation.size()) != 1) //it is impossible to do 2+2* 
 {
     System.out.println("ERROR");
 }
 for(int x =0; x< s2.length-1;x++)//loops through array picking out operand
 {
       if(!isOperation(s2[x]))
       {
           list.add(Integer.parseInt(s2[x]));// If it throws exception. The problem is here
       }
       else
       {
          Operation.add(s2[x]);
       }
 }
```

Ok so we added the values in the original string to either a Number list or an operation list. Next, We need to put it all together.

```
 int total = list.get(0); // as the equation begins with the first number
 int OperationIndex = 0;
  for(int x =1; x< list.size()-1;x++)
  {
        switch(Operation.get(OperationIndex))
        {
             case "+": total+= list.get(x);
             case "-": total-= list.get(x);
             case "/": total/= list.get(x);
             case "*": total*= list.get(x);
             default: total =0;
        }
        Operation Index++;
  }
 System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

This should work. it encompasses all that you need. Other changes are minor, and I am almost 100% positive that you can figure those out to change the program to your liking..

Comment: @mathfinder new solution